# Adjust the percentage of training data for MobileNet

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to train a MobileNet to recognize custom image classes.
But I don't know, how to tell the MobileNet how much of the provided data should be used as training data.

When you use the retrain script:

[image]

I can set the validation and testing percentage. 
The big question is, how are these percentages calculated?

Does the program use 100% and splits it into 75% training, 10% validation, 15% testing?
Or does MobileNet seperat in advance into 70% training data and 30% testing data and then takes 10% of the 70% as validation data?

I dont understand how this works inside MobileNet?
Can I adjust the percentage of training data to 85% for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Tensorflow's documentation on MobileNet](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining), the **--testing_percentage** and **--validation_percentage** parameters control the following:

> The usual split is to put 80% of the images into the main training set, keep 10% aside to run as validation frequently during training, and then have a final 10% that are used less often as a testing set to predict the real-world performance of the classifier. These ratios can be controlled using the **--testing_percentage** and **--validation_percentage** flags.

So I believe with your current parameters (--testing_percentage=15, --validation_percentage=10), you will have 75% of the data used in the main training set, 15% used for testing, and 10% for validation as you suggested.

If you wanted to increase your percentage of training data from 75% to 85%, you could do it by setting:

--testing_percentage=10 and --validation_percentage=5

or

--testing_percentage=5 and --validation_percentage=10

or any other combination that leaves 85% of the data for training.

i.e.: **training% = 100% - test% - validation%**

You'll want to be careful not to set your testing/validation percentages too low, however, or your accuracy scores may not have enough testing data to verify that your prediction accuracy score is, itself, accurate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Rudy! That's just what I needed. Now I can understand the whole mobilnet retrain process better!!
Great help